# How do I prevent IE from opening itself when pressing Ctrl+Shift+A?

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer-8

Whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> IE opens a popup window that says 'enter abbreviation', even when IE isn't open and I'm in a different program. My computer (Vista) has IE8 installed on it, but if fixing the problem means uninstalling it, that's fine.

Comment: What happens if you enter something at the prompt? (I suspect it's some add-on, if so, the result might help identify it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same thing on my work computer. Nothing happens when I enter text and hit enter. The window just disappears.

/edit: Ha! It's from Notepad++. The Zen Coding plugin adds that popup, and Notepad++ doesn't appear to keep its hotkeys local.